# How can I get a website's images to increase in size, relative to their page views or hits?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, pageviews, image-size

#### The scenario:

I have a very basic html site with a series of images lumped together, side by side. The images are also linked to corresponding articles and when the cursor hovers over each image, a large description of the linked article is generated in the center of the page.

#### The goal:

1. I would like the images to grow in size, some percent, relative to the number of pageviews the image's linked article receives. The more hits the article gets, the larger the image link.
2. Simultaneously, the images (which vary in their aspect ratios/dimensions), would automatically get re-ordered, or shuffled around to best fit the page in a responsive manner.

Any thoughts, ideas, or opinions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to use some server side language for this, like php. In best case php + MySQL... Javascript is not enough if you want to have information on number of hits on server side...

Answer (score 1):

I think the best starting point for this would be flex-box which you can learn about [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/).

The important aspect here is (from the same source, above):

box-flex
 Values: 0 | Any integer
 The flexibility ratio for this child. If a child had 1 and its sibling had 2, any additional space in the parent box would be consumed twice as much by the sibling. It defaults to 0 which  is inflexible.

So you can set this to make some boxes take up more space than others and so on. Though you'd need to do some math for this obviously.

Comment: I'm reading-up on flexbox right now.  So far, it seems like the right direction to be headed in, and it doesn't require a lot of overhead. I definitely have some homework to do, though!  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I tried up-voting your response, but it says: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".  I just recently signed-up, but hopefully 15 won't take too long to achieve.

Comment: :) Ok, no worries. Glad to see you wanting to get there.